# Why non deductible template parameters is problematic?

Tags: c++11, templates, c++14, metaprogramming

Trying to compile this piece of code results in an error.

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClass;

template <typename T, std::size_t sz>
struct MyClass<T> {
    static void print() {
        std::cout << "Partially specialized" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

> error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization

Trying to make it possible to deduce `sz` solves the problem. For example:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t sz>
struct MyClass<T[sz]> {
    static void print() {
        std::cout << "Partially specialized" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

My question is, how does the compiler interprets such a program and what's the rational behind not allowing to have the first structure?

Further clarification:
I am thinking that if the inital code was compilable, we could use it in a manner such as: `MyClass<int, 4>::print()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am thinking that if the inital code was compilable, we could use it in a manner such as: `MyClass<int, 4>::print()`.

That's not how template specialization works. If you declare the base template as `template <class T> struct MyClass` then `MyClass` can only be instantiated with just one template type parameter. It cannot be instantiated as `MyClass<int, int>` or `MyClass<int, 3>` or `MyClass<3>`.

Template specialization can just *specialize* on the base template parameters.

Going back to your problem. So `MyClass` can be instantiated like so: `MyClass<int>`, `MyClass<float>`, `MyClass<SomeClass>`, `MyClass<int*>`, `MyClass<int[10]>` and so on and so on.

When you write

```
template <typename T, std::size_t sz>
struct MyClass<T[sz]> {
```

You specialize the template `MyClass<T>` for any `T` that is an array or any type of any size. For instance `MyClass<int[24]>` will use this specialization.

When you write

```
template <typename T, std::size_t sz>
struct MyClass<T> {
//             ^
//             no sz here
```

That looks like a specialization of `MyClass` but it is not, because `sz` does not appear in the specialization paramters.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, after we declare a template, we can specialize it if we like, e.g.:

```
template <typename T> foo;
template <typename U> foo<U*>;
```

the compiler will now expect a different definition for pointer types. But - the specialization needs to actually specialize - it can't be as general as the original declaration. In your case, you're *adding* a template parameter. It's not even about its deduction - it's just not something you can do.

Thus, if you look at the error messages [other compiles give you](https://godbolt.org/z/D1M10U):

(clang:)

```
<source>:7:8: error: class template partial specialization does not specialize any template argument; to define the primary template, remove the template argument list
struct MyClass<T> {
       ^      ~~~
<source>:6:1: error: too many template parameters in template redeclaration
template <typename T, std::size_t sz>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

(MSVC:)

```
<source>(11): error C2753: 'MyClass<T>': partial specialization cannot match argument list for primary template
<source>(11): error C2764: 'sz': template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization 'MyClass<T>'
```

You'll see the different focus in error message rhetoric: You must specialize, and yet you aren't.

On the other hand, in your second code snippet, you *are* specializing: Now you're not defining `MyClass` for all types `T`, but only for arrays of a certain number of elements. You should really think about it as:

```
template <typename U, std::size_t sz>
struct MyClass<U[sz]> {
    static void print() {
        std::cout << "Partially specialized" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

so the specialization is for when `T` is of the form `U[sz]`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please elaborate on your first sentence? In particular, what do you mean it doesn't make sense? The second code snippet compiles and functions well.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Considering the second code snippet, we can add a second template parameter. So, can you please also elaborate this statement of yours: "In your case, you're adding a template parameter. It's not even about its deduction - it's just not something you can do."